# NetBeans profiler showing vastly different execution times

Tags: java, performance, netbeans, profiling, profiler

I am benchmarking two algorithms for solving the Skyline query problem on a file with 2-dimensional points.

I declare them:

`SkylineAlgorithm bnl = new BNL();
SkylineAlgorithm sfs = new SFS();`

Then manually measure their performance:

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
List<Point> skylinesBnl = bnl.getSkylinePoints(file);
long endTime = System.nanoTime();
long durationBnl = (endTime - startTime) / 1000000;

startTime = System.nanoTime();
List<Point> skylinesSfs = sfs.getSkylinePoints(file);
endTime = System.nanoTime();
long durationSfs = (endTime - startTime) / 1000000;

System.out.println("BNL: " + durationBnl + " ms");
System.out.println("SFS: " + durationSfs + " ms");
```

For example this will print:

```
BNL: 4648 ms
SFS: 4946 ms
```

Then I thought of using something more sophisticated like the NetBeans profiler. I set the root profiling method to `getSkylinePoints(file)` (both algorithms share that method though a template method design pattern) then at the end of the line `List<Point> skylinesBnl = bnl.getSkylinePoints(file);` I set the profiler to save results and output them. Same happens for sfs.

My results this way are these (open images in new tab):

**BNL:**

[image: BNL]

**SFS:**

[image: SFS]

That is vastly different from what I am getting through the manual way. Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple : `getPointRDDFromTextFile` apparently uses disk I/O and produces a more complex result. If you get rid of the I/O-op you will decrease your execution-time drastically. Accessing drives of any (!) kind is always very slow - by design.

The same thing is true for sockets of any kind (except for sockets to in-memory pipes) hence WAN/LAN data transmissions and also recursive algorithms of any kind (because of stack-multiplication)

To get similar results you will need to pre-fetch your file and read it from memory ... if it is small enough, of course.

Comment: So in theory since both algorithms access the same file the difference between them should be the same right? Meaning since in NetBeans I have a ~200ms difference I should have the same difference in my manual way. In my manual way though there is a ~300ms difference, is this just within the margin of error (since I don't do multiple iterations and average from them)? Also is it possible with the NetBeans profiler to also count the disk I/O? Maybe by not excluding the `java.io` package from the filter?

Comment: i ... fail to understand what you are asking. Maybe google translate might help you.

Comment: What do you not understand exactly so I can explain it better? English is my mother language and I am unable to see where I have gone syntactically wrong.